# java ignore https certificate validation

Tags: java, https, certificate

I want to connect to a https url and ignore the certification on it. But there are several problems.
I tried different implementations:

1. http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/trustall.html

With this implementation I got

```
    java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <my.domain.com>
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:524)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:448)
at                                                                                            sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at com.unister.semweb.monitoring.moto.utils.TrustQA.subscribe(TrustQA.java:41)
at com.unister.semweb.monitoring.moto.MotoServiceTest.testGetIdFromCockpit(MotoServiceTest.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The domain I typed in is my.domain.com

1. I tried to turn of the Hostname validation by adding

   ```
     // Create all-trusting host name verifier
   HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
       public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
           return true;
       }
   };
   // Install the all-trusting host verifier
   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
   ```

As it is there: http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/
But I get this exception

```
    java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1446)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at com.unister.semweb.monitoring.moto.utils.TrustQA.subscribe(TrustQA.java:51)
at com.unister.semweb.monitoring.moto.MotoServiceTest.testGetIdFromCockpit(MotoServiceTest.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I don't know what I could do anymore. I have to ignore the certificate. There is no other option.

Any suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to?

Comment: the complete https url e.g. https://my.domain.com/here/is?do=this (there is https:// for my.domain...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution now. It isn't the problem with the certificate ignore. Therefore is this link here usefull.

The reason why the redirects comes is that I have to authentication myself.  So I add the class I found under [http auth](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html)

```
    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
        // and Negotiate, the usrname and password are all the same.
        System.err.println("Feeding username and password for "
                + getRequestingScheme());
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
    }
}
```

and add the class via:

```
    Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
```